# pass the Print statement output to Flask template

Tags: python, flask

```
@app.route("/upload_file", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def upload_file():
d={}
if request.method == 'POST':
    df = pd.read_csv(request.files.get('file'), encoding="ISO-8859-1", engine="python")
    links = df['live_url'].tolist()
    for i in links:
       for key,value in xml_data.items():
                  if i in value:
                     d.setdefault(key,[]).append(i)
    res= d.items()


 

    return render_template('results1.html', res= res, d=d)
return render_template('results1.html')
```

Hi there,

Please can someone be able to assist me on how to pass the below print output to result template.
Thank you in advance.

Here is the below code for the result template. it takes input from search template and produce the result to result template:

search1.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron" style="background:transparent !important">
      <center>
        <h2>Marketing Search</h2>
      </center>
    </div>
  </div>

  <form method="POST" action="/upload_file" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="margin:auto;max-width:25%;padding:50px;">
    <p><input type="file" name="file" value="file"></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Upload"></p>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

results.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron" style="background:transparent !important"><center><h2>Marketing Search</h2></center>
    </div></div>
<form class="example" action="/search/results" method="post" style="margin:auto;max-width:25%">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="input">
  <button type="submit" class="btn"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
</form>
<br/>
<center>
      <h3>{{ res }} Results</h3>
</center>
<br/>
<table class="table">
  <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
        <th>Environment</th>
        <th>Internal Name</th>
        <th>Link</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
 {% for n,m in d.items() %}
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>{{n}}</td>
    <td>{{m}}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>


{% block scripts %}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='se.js') }}"></script>

{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the above code for my templates.

Comment: how does the template look like? what's the placeholder's name?

Comment: short answer is: you can't, I don't even understand how you thought that would work, you will need to use html and jinja to create a loop in the template, in the html template, create a for loop there using what jinja2 offers, simple stuff really, if you don't know I can suggest you look at this [tutorial by Corey Schafer](https://youtu.be/QnDWIZuWYW0?list=PL-osiE80TeTs4UjLw5MM6OjgkjFeUxCYH&t=286) (link is set to specific time where this is starting to get explained)

Comment: I am new here @Matiiss . So, playing with all the available option. I  have used a for loop but then the result is blank or empty.

Comment: @Revanth ok, but haven't you observed what `print` does? it prints to the command line so ... ok anyways take a look at the tutorial I linked to, it should explain how to use loops with jinja2

Comment: Sure @Matiiss,Thank you. I will take a look, but the problem is it doesn't event print anything to command line. So, I am wondering if my for loop is working properly or not. So,the functionality is when I upload a csv file --> it should read the file --> convert it in to a list --> print the matching key, values(from list) from xml_data.

Comment: the loop probably works (if method is post) but I think there have been multiple questions on that nothing gets printed to command line when using flask (if you wanted to see sth in command line you should `import logging` and then in the loop instead of print do `logging.info(f'{data_or_st}')` then you may see it appear in command line (maybe you have to basiconfig it too but maybe you don't)) otherwise if you want to show sth in the template, you should pass the whole iterable to the template and iterate in the template (what the tutorial I linked to also covers)

Comment: hi @Matiiss, i tried using the for loop as mentioned in the video, it shows empty dictionary with out any result.

Comment: so, it is not working when i use the if condition and first for loop , when I removed the if condition just to check if its printing properly or not then I can see the output in result template.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you test the api POST request separately using Postman. You can select the csv file you want to upload there from your filesystem as form-data with "file" as a key, and your csv as the value. Dont forget to change the method to POST.
Instead of rendering the html in this case, return res and d directly (as json), so Postman can display it.

If it works via Postman, you can rule out that the behaviour is broken in the backend, and then debug the error in the search1 or results htmls.

I think your dictionary is empty (when you use it in the results template) because it is already empty when it is passed to the template after upload (res and d). Also, I am not quite sure why you are using res and d separately.

Comment: it was solved now,, the only issue  the links in csv file are of different length when compared with links in xml data  that has tracking parameter to it. So, i am getting a blank output.